# How to raise error if field used for mongodb index creation does not exist in the collection?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

When creating an index in mongodb and/or pymongo, it does not seem to check if the referenced field actually exists or not.

For example when running the mongo shell command:

```
db.myCollection.createIndex({"InexistingFieldasdlkajsdljad": 1})
```

Whatever string you use, an index is created, no matter if it is actually a schema field or not.

Is there a way to perform this check, i.e., before actually creating the index check if this field exist or not? Or at least to check if this index works? Furthermore is it possible to apply this check to nested field index creation?

In my db I've defined a validation schema, so that might be used to perform such a check (?). In particular, all documents share the same keys, so there is no danger/need that one key will be part of one document but not of the other.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
const c = db.myCollection.countDocuments( { InexistingFieldasdlkajsdljad: { $exists: true } } )
if ( c > 0 ) 
   db.myCollection.createIndex({"InexistingFieldasdlkajsdljad": 1})
```

However, from performance it would be rather poor. I suggest to create a [partial index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/):

```
db.myCollection.createIndex(
   { InexistingFieldasdlkajsdljad: 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: { InexistingFieldasdlkajsdljad: { $exists: true } } }
)
```

Yes, the index is created in any case. But if you have no document with this field, then the index does not consume any disc space (by default non-existing fields or empty values are indexed) nor has any other impact. And you have one benefit: As soon as such field is added to any document, then the indexing is available immediately.

Comment: As it is, this command is pretty obscure but it looks you are doing something like this: you are getting the indexes with `getIndexes`, then you are looking for an index name. If that index name is not found, then create the index.

But this is not what I want: I want to create the index if the field is found among the collection possible keys, and ONLY if it is found I want to create the index.